# HTML Email : adjust vertical line height according to the content in another td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to adjust vertical line height as per the content of `<td>` tag.

```html
<table class="bg-color1" style="background-color:#ffffff;border:none;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; " align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" >
                    <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="28%" valign="top" style=" border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace:0pt; border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left:70px; text-align: center; ">
                            <span style="text-align: center">8:30 - 9:30</span>
                        </td>

                        <td width="7%" valign="top" style=";mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace:0pt; border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-left: 70px; padding-top: 10px; ">
                            <hr style="height: 20px;">
                        </td>

                        <td width="65%" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace:0pt; border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: 500; font-size: 15px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left; ">
                                Tea, Registration, Networking
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr style="border: thin black solid;">
                        <td width="28%" valign="top" style=" border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace:0pt; border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left:70px; text-align: center; ">
                            <span style="text-align: center">8:30 - 9:30</span>
                        </td>

                        <td width="7%" valign="top" style=";mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace:0pt; border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-left: 70px; padding-top: 10px; ">
                            <hr style="height: 20px;">
                        </td>

                        <td width="65%" valign="top" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace:0pt; border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: 500; font-size: 15px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left; ">
                            Tea, Registration, Networking
                            Tea, Registration, Networking
                            Tea, Registration, Networking
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                    </tbody>


                    <tr>
                        <td height="40"></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Now What I want is when the content of **third** `<td>` changes then as per the changes the height of vertical line and the time of 1st `<td>` should be adjusted to center of the `<td>` tag.

[image: here it the image]

I want output as per the image.

PS : As I am making HTML Email , I can't use `<div>` , **position** property. I have to stick to **table** and **inline css** only.

Thank You.

Comment: Stupid question, but why do some tds have `align="left"` as well as `style="text-align:center"`? What does that achieve?

Comment: do apologize for that. I am new to HTML email. so I want my vertical line to be adjustable as per the content which is in third `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `padding-top: xx;` in the first TD's with `vertical-align: middle;` seems to work.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/j3qy132b/1/

I played around a bit further, if it's of use to anyone..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/j3qy132b/3/

A faint border-left instead of boxshadow

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/j3qy132b/4/

Comment: i can't use third party library such as jQuery , and i also want to expand **vertical line** according to content.

Comment: the jquery is just for demonstration purposes. ignore the css and the javascript panes.

Comment: the second fiddle i posted addresses the vertical line issue, i removed the hr's and used box-shadow instead.

Comment: cant' you put hr as there is a need for the same. that's why

Comment: I could probably do it with flexbox but it would take some work, redoing entire table. And I'm not sure how cross browser compatible flex + tables would be. Flexbox on non-tables alone has problems with all versions of IE, especially with vertical sizing. Check this post about HR. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/hr-on-height/

Comment: ohkk.. i can do one thing, I can take two `td` in `tr` and to the 2nd `td` I can give border-left and padding to make content looks like in image. can I do so?

Comment: You can do that for sure. That's what I originally did but I was unable to apply padding to the top and bottom of each TR to 1. separate the borders vertically from the border you had and 2. not make it look like one long line down the page. I added a new fiddle, if you replace the background color I added with your original borders you'll see what I mean about #1. #2 was fixed when i added the tr spacers between each tr block.

Comment: Thank you.. that's what I wanted... :)